# How to specify multiple subnets for Lambdas using serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm trying to use the [example code](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/) to specify that my Lambda be available in multiple subnets:

```
provider:
  vpc: # Optional VPC. But if you use VPC then both subproperties (securityGroupIds and subnetIds) are required
    securityGroupIds:
      - securityGroupId1
      - securityGroupId2
    subnetIds:
      - subnetId1
      - subnetId2
```

However, I've tried several variations on this, with several different errors, and I can only ever get it to work with a single subnet specified.

```
provider:
  name:       aws
  runtime:    python3.8
  memorySize: 512
  lambdaHashingVersion: '20201221'
  stage: dev
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
    - sg-06e65a1f67c7XXXX
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-e84fXXXX
      – subnet-6e2cXXXX
```

`Cannot parse "serverless.yml": bad indentation of a mapping entry in "$FOLDER/serverless.yml" (45:7)`

Another attempt, with just a change in indentation:

```
provider:
  name:       aws
  runtime:    python3.8
  memorySize: 512
  lambdaHashingVersion: '20201221'
  stage: dev
  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
    - sg-06e65a1f67c7XXXX
    subnetIds:
    - subnet-e84fXXXX
    – subnet-6e2cXXXX
```

`Cannot parse "serverless.yml": can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missed in "$FOLDER/serverless.yml" (45:22)`

I also tried variations with indenting the `securityGroupIds` two spaces, with the same results.  Any ideas appreciated.  My thought is that this seems like a bug in the serverless framework, like it's expecting key pairs rather than a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the subnets section the second `-` is not a `-`. It's a different character. Try to delete it and replace it with an normal hyphen.

The error occurs because it can't parse the file as valid yaml due to that character.

Comment: Unicode will get you every time.  Many thanks!  I'll accept this answer as soon as the ten minute delay is up.  I've set `vim` to highlight the oddball dashes just in case I see this in the future.